# How can I create an ORM for crud operations with nested objects using reflection and ado.net?

Tags: c#, orm, ado.net, system.reflection

I want to create a class `ORM<T>` which will have 5 methods.
1. Insert (T item)
2. Update (T item)
3. Delete (T item)
4. Delete (int id)
5. GetById (int id)
6. GetAll ()

T should be a class that always has an int id. It can be made an abstract base class or interface to enforce this in generic constraint.

The ORM should also be capable of handling nesting objects.

```
class Room{ 
public int Id { get; set; } 
public List<Chair> chairs { get; set; } 
}
class Chair {
 public int Id { get; set; } 
 public double cost { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Using reflection with ORM is an _oxymoron_

Answer (score 0):

get data inside stored procedure  and split data inside sp and insert using for Json Path